# php - system command parameter output show results in one line using IE

Tags: php

i use this script to execute a shell from IE , while in the cli its been outputed correctly in the browser i see the results in one big line

```
    <?php



$a = $_POST['a'];
$i=$_POST['i'];

$output = system("./xx.sh $i $a");

echo wordwrap($output,180,"<br />\n");

?>
```

Comment: what does it look like if you "view source"?

Comment: in the source of the browser it's look ok.

Comment: The page is HTML, so it doesn't display line feeds in text. The `wordwrap()` function puts the line feeds in, but they're not HTML line breaks (ie `<br>` tags), so the browser won't show them. @DanFromGermany's answer is correct; you need to include `<br>` tags where you want line feeds to be displayed. `nl2br()` will do that for you.

Comment: Oh, by the way -- be very careful of allowing post data into a `system()` call without validating or escaping it; it would be very easy for a hacker to do some serious damage to your system by posting specific values into `$i` or $a`.

Comment: thanks, my system in intranet env so it is ecured (i hope), anyway i tried all @DanFromGermany examples but it didint work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of wordwrap:

```
echo nl2br($output);
```

transforms line ending characters (`\r\n`) to `<br />`s

or combine:

```
echo wordwrap(nl2br($output), 180, "<br />\n");
```

or use `<pre>` for preformatted code:

```
echo "<pre>" .  wordwrap($output, 180) . "</pre>";
```

Comment: thanks for your quik answers,but none of this combinations worked for me. as i mantioned above in my answer to @Spudley, in the source of the browser page it's look ok.

Comment: telnet> Trying xx.xx.xx.xx
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx
Escape character is '^]'.
 
You have new mail.
End of user profile
host>cd /home/scripts
host>./test _alarm.sh <variable to find>
--------------------
connecting to host1
--------------------
some text 180 charcters long 
 
--------------------
connecting to host2
--------------------

some text 180 charcters long 

and so on to all other hosts

Comment: I can't see weather this output has `\n` chars in it now, if not, either your script `xx.sh` removes to new line characters or it hasn't any, or other unknown line breaks :S sorry, can't help more on this